# Can this JS be written in pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

```
jQuery('.parent:visible').each(function () {
  if (jQuery(this).find('.child-1').is(':hidden')) {
    jQuery(this).find('.child-2').css('color', '#000')
  }
});
```

Selecting the children are easy, separately, but since there are no `if` statements in CSS, I'm hoping there's some magic CSS I'm missing.

edit: fixing js as per suggestions

Comment: Have you tried using ':hidden'?

Comment: Your `if()` condition will never fail the way you have it written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.parent:not(.hidden) .child-1:not(.hidden) + .child-2` perhaps?

---

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/3dv7mzfd/)

```css
.parent { border:1px solid red; }
.hidden { display:none; }

.parent:not(.hidden) .child-1:not(.hidden) + .child-2 {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">one</div>
    <div class="child-2">two</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1 hidden">one</div>
    <div class="child-2">two</div>
</div>

<div class="parent hidden">
    <div class="child-1">one</div>
    <div class="child-2">two</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">one</div>
    <div class="child-2">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not completely equivalent to the JS version since `.child-1` and `.child-2` elements are not necessarily siblings (they can be intricated or one is the child of a sibling of the other, ...)

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie True. I guess OP should post his HTML structure then. I just assumed things.

Comment: Even though I didn't specify it, they are definitely siblings. This would also work with `:visible` and `:hidden` instead of your .hidden class checks... do you know if IE (8+) will have any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add classes to the elements based on their visibility, then you can do this.

```
.parent.visible .child-1.not-visible + .child-2 {
    color: #000
}
```

This will check if a `.child-1` inside a `.parent.visible` has a class of `.not-visible` -- if it does, then the **[adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** with a class `.child-2` will inherit this rule.

Otherwise, you have to use JavaScript as CSS doesn't have a way to **test** if an element is visible or not.